# How to center div with two inline buttons in it (css)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm currently designing a webpage using Bootstrap and I have two `<a>` buttons laid inline with each other inside of the `<div class="jumbotron"></div>`

Here's the HTML code:

```
   <div class="jumbotron hub-jumbo">
        <div class="hub-header">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="txt-white">Jason's Summer Vacation</h2>
                <p class="txt-white">There doesn't seem to be a description here!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hub-btns">
            <a class="copy-link btn btn-lg btn-wide bg-white" href="" role="button">Copy Link</a>
            <a class="create-drop btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-wide txt-white bg-blue border-blue ripple" href="" role="button">Create Drop</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the CSS of the div wrapping the buttons and the buttons themselves:

```
.hub-btns {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.hub-btns .copy-link {
    border-bottom-color: #EBEBEB;
}

.hub-btns .create-drop:hover {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
}

.hub-btns .create-drop:focus {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    border-bottom-color: #0398db;
}

.hub-btns a {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

I'm still not great with CSS so I'm probably missing something obvious here. But, I simply want to take the div that is wrapping the two buttons and center that div within the jumbotron div.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If an answer is helpful to you, it would be nice if you accepted that answer.

Answer (score 4):

I made some changes in a class name (removed spaces) and put some borders for your better understanding of the div placing. Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.jumbotron-hub-jumbo {
margin: 0 auto;
border:2px solid black;
width:300px;
}

.hub-btns {
    margin: 0 auto;
 width:200px;
 border:2px solid green;
}

.hub-btns .copy-link {
    border-bottom-color: #EBEBEB;
}

.hub-btns .create-drop:hover {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
}

.hub-btns .create-drop:focus {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    border-bottom-color: #0398db;
}

.hub-btns a {
 width:200px;
 border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="jumbotron-hub-jumbo">
        <div class="hub-header">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="txt-white">Jason's Summer Vacation</h2>
                <p class="txt-white">There doesn't seem to be a description here!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hub-btns">
            <a class="copy-link btn btn-lg btn-wide bg-white" href="" role="button">Copy Link</a>
            <a class="create-drop btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-wide txt-white bg-blue border-blue ripple" href="" role="button">Create Drop</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In the HTML I just changed class `jumbotron hub-jumbo`

I saw you said you are new to CSS, don't be afraid seeing HTML and CSS merged together. Just cut style part and paste it into your style.css.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to help without seeing what you're trying to do.
Adding `text-align: center;` inside the `.hub-btns` should be enough to center align those buttons.

Also, I would probably move the `margin: 0 10px;` to `.hub-btns`instead of applying it the anchors/buttons directly.

Lastly, if you don't need to support old browsers, try to invest some time learning the basics of flexbox. It makes our life a lot easier when it comes to 'aligning things'.

Comment: Lovely, my team mate added that right as I was checking this. Thanks!